# How should I rewrite this map() example using list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [17,12,11,10]
>>> c = [-1,-4,5,9]

>>> list(map(lambda x,y,z:x+y+z, a,b,c))
[17, 10, 19, 23]
```

Tried:

```
>>>[(x+y+z) for x in a for y in b for z in c]
```

but got addition of every possible combination of elements of those lists (not just first-with-first, second-with-second etc.):

```
[17, 14, 23, 27, 12, 9, 18, 22, 11, 8, 17, 21, 10, 7, 16, 20, 18, 15, 24, 28, 13, 10, 19, 23, 12, 9, 18, 22, 11, 8, 17, 21, 19, 16, 25, 29, 14, 11, 20, 24, 13, 10, 19, 23, 12, 9, 18, 22, 20, 17, 26, 30, 15, 12, 21, 25, 14, 11, 20, 24, 13, 10, 19, 23]
```

Is this possible at all? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip), which drives multiple iterables 'in lock-step':

```
[x+y+z for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)]
```

Your original attempt produces the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the three lists. There exists [a helper function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for Cartesian products in the `itertools` module.

Comment: Alternatively, `[sum(row) for row in zip(a,b,c)]`.

Answer (score 1):

One possibilty:

```
In [36]:

[ a[i] + b[i] + c[i] for i in range(len(a))]
Out[36]:
[17, 10, 19, 23]
```

This assumes all lists are the same length

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it would be:

```
answerList = [] 
for key,value in enumerate(a):   
    answerList.append(a[key]+b[key]+c[key])
```

Comment: `a` is a list, not a `dict`

Comment: corrected. I had missed the enumerate function earlier.